# Web3j cannot connect from docker container

Tags: java, docker, blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

I have a java application in docker container. It try to connect to my private blockchain using web bean.
And there is some problem: Unable to determine sync status of node

I thought that the port is not accessible, but it is open to all.

If I execute my jar file not in docker container - all OK, it work.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't exposed port in container?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose >> expose article

Comment: Please post this as a comment.  If you are unable to due to reputation, then please gain some.

Comment: I exposed all needed ports